# Xamarin Forms app crash during startup (Android - Phisycal device)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash, startup

i deployed app developed with xamarin forms (5) and it works perfectly on IOS and Android, BUT some specific device like these (Vivo y21, Realme C55) app crash during startup.

The thing very strange is from appcenter i not recognize any crash log, so seems something happens during OnCreate method in MainActivity or something like that.

**Device have android 12.**

I'll post here my MainActivity and if is possible video during crash on these devices.

```
using System;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using OneSignalSDK.Xamarin;
using OneSignalSDK.Xamarin.Core;
using FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform;
using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Droid;
using Java.Security;
using MyPad.Helpers;
using PanCardView.Droid;
using Plugin.FacebookClient;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Facebook;
using Xamarin.Facebook.AppEvents;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace MyPad.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyPad",
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
        MainLauncher = false, LaunchMode =LaunchMode.SingleTop,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
            CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
            FacebookClientManager.Initialize(this);

            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            Popup.Init(this);            
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinAndroid.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Auth.CustomTabsConfiguration.CustomTabsClosingMessage = null;
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ColorExtensions.ToAndroid(Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#181A1F")));
            Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            OneSignal.Default.Initialize("3cefddff-d624-4a1a-8501-d00c3ca74e93");
            OneSignal.Default.PromptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse();
            CardsViewRenderer.Preserve();
            FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(this.ApplicationContext);
            FacebookSdk.AutoInitEnabled = true;
            FacebookSdk.FullyInitialize();
            FacebookSdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true;
            App.ScreenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
            App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnResume();
            AppEventsLogger.ActivateApp(Application);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            FacebookClientManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        }

        public class Env : IEnvironment
        {
            public void SetStatusBarColor(System.Drawing.Color color, bool darkStatusBarTint)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                    return;

                var activity = Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity;
                var window = activity.Window;
                window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                window.ClearFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
                window.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToPlatformColor());

                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
                {
                    var flag = (Android.Views.StatusBarVisibility)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
                    window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = darkStatusBarTint ? flag : 0;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported =false)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "mypadapp")]
    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
    }

}
```

I tried to create emulator with these device specs but it runs perfectly.
Maybe issue with external libreries?

Comment: In the Output panel in Visual Studio do you see anything in the Debug output? Anything in the Xamarin Diagnostics output?